# where am I going wrong where my code wont echo certain parts?

Tags: php, authentication

Where am I going wrong to get my code to display an error message such as, "you did not fill in all the fields" or "username/password is taken"? 
I have the login working and everything is fine and for now, I have the error displayed in the header bar but I also want it displayed on the form.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    //Error handlers
    //Check for empty fields
    if(empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        echo "you did not fill in all the fields";
        exit();
    } else {
        //Check if input char are valid
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
            exit();
        } else {
            //Check if email is valid
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email");
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid= '$uid'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                    echo "the username you have entered is taken";
                    exit();
                } else {
                    //Hashing the password
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    //Insert the user into the database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }


} else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It's not displaying because you are redirecting the user to another page after displaying the error code.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are redirecting the page first and then showing the message which make no sense. If you want to show the message maybe you can use this way:

```
if(empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {

    $msg = "you did not fill in all the fields";
    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty&errmsg=$msg");
    exit();
}
```

And on signup.php page use something like

```
if($errmsg)
  echo $errmsg;
```